# Generate different hash number for all possible array combinations

Tags: arrays, node.js, combinations

Assume I have an array of 10 items eg: `["name0", "name1" ... "name9"];`

Now I want to create a function that can hash all different combinations with different numbers such that, when I have the number I can find what array combination that is eg: 542535 -> item1, item3 and item4. etc. For obvious reasons the number should be unique.

This will not be used for security reasons therefore I dont mind about that.

Do you have any suggestion how I should go about this.

*EDIT:*

Assuming we have a smaller array holding 2 items then, by calling generate_combination_nums(the_array); we should get,

0 -> "name0"

1 -> "name1"

2 -> "name0", "name1"

So now we know what number each combination of that array belongs to.

Comment: Are all the items in the array unique? Also, hashing is one way. You can check if a particular combination of values in the array matches a hash. You can't work in reverse.

Comment: Yes, all items are unique, and they are all strings.

Comment: Hmm then hashing isnt an option cause I need it to be two ways.

Comment: What is the use of this? Seems like if all the strings are unique, you can just join them with a delimiter. I still don't understand the use of this.

Comment: I would like to store the number in MySQL and upon retrieving it, know what the combination was, I dont really want to store a really long string for each user.

Comment: Can strings be anything? Or are there only fixed number of strings to choose from? Also, are there only 10 strings in the array?